# How to clear screen on Python 3.4.2 shell?

Tags: windows-7, shell, python

I am trying to clear the screen on python 3.4.2 shell, I used clear screen, clear(), cls, clrscr etc. But no one is working, Please let me know the command to clear the screen.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> should do what you want

Comment: its not working friend with ctrl + L

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
cls = lambda: os.system('cls')
cls()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a new and very simple python module out.. it'll work in the shell and works for both Windows and Linux:

[pypi](https://pypi.org/project/clear-screen/)

```
sudo pip3 install clear-shell

from clear_shell import clear

clear()
```

Typing `clear()` is much easier and faster in my opinion.